# ifFile Does not recognize csv, pl, sh, xml files

Tags: java, txt

I'm building an array of a recursive search of a directory. That part works great, but when trying to determine if a file is a file, it only adds .txt files into the array, and skips over files like csv, pl, sh, xml and so on. Is the something I can do to fix this? here is the code I'm working with.

```
            public static ArrayList<Object> listDirectory(String directory) {
                
                Object sbytes;
                File dir = new File((String) directory);
                File[] firstLevelFiles = dir.listFiles();
                ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList <Object>();

                 if (firstLevelFiles != null) {
                    for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
            
                        //if (aFile.isFile()) {
                        if (! aFile.isDirectory()) {

                            System.out.println("[" + aFile.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
                            
                            long bytes = aFile.length();
                            if (bytes > 1000) {
                                sbytes = bytes / 1000 + " Kb";
                            } else if (bytes > 1000000){
                                sbytes = bytes / 1000000 + " Mb";
                            } else {
                                sbytes = bytes + " bytes";
                            }
                            
                            Object fileName = aFile.getName();
                            
                            Object nameAndSize = fileName + " " + sbytes;
                         
                           
                            array.add(nameAndSize);
                            
                        } else {
                       
                             ArrayList<Object> deeperList = listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                array.addAll(deeperList);
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
               
                return array;

            }
```

Comment: These files in the diretory, is you creating with the Java aplication or another way?

Comment: With various methods, not via java, but with git bash, new file, perl scripts, and so on. Does the way the files are created matter?

Comment: Maybe.. I dont understanded very well the documentation, it says that `isFile` return `true` when is a normal File, and says "Any non-directory file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file". [Learn more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()).